# Geocoding error in ArcMap - OS Open Names Locator

Tags: mapping, geocoding, arcgis, arcmap

I am trying to geocode a set of 723 UK postcodes using OS_Codepointopen_postcode_locator.

My database is in the following format:

**ID | SAON | PAON | Street | Locality | Town | Postcode**

I am attempting to geocode just the postcodes as precise locations are not neccesary. 
The process I have used so far goes like this:

**Import table.xslx > Open table attributes (in Table of Contents) > Right click file and select Geocode > Select OS_Codepointopen_postcode_locator > Select single field and direct to 'postcode' column.**

After starting the geocode process the program immediately presents the error message ***"Create Feature Class: There was an error trying to process this table."***

I have then tried to export the .xlsx table in ArcMap to give the table an OID column. This presented the same error. After this I converted the export to a dBASE file, alas this presented the same error again.

I have also attempted to take a smaller snippet of the database, using only 20 items and have removed all other information leaving just the postcode and an identification numbered column as suggestions state that it may be a processing power bottleneck. However, this presents exactly the same error.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of trying to find information online and merely minutes after posting this question **I have found a solution.**

Posting here so that others in the same situation have an answer.

**After importing your .xlsx table into ArcMap open the table attributes > Export to a new table by following instructions > Open ArcToolbox > Expand Geocoding tab >  Geocode Addresses > Use OS_open_names_locator > Follow instructions ensuring that the Multiple field option is selected and ensure 'none' is selected for any fields you do not have in your database.**

Running this initially only matched around half the addresses because it was still looking for full_address, so unmarking that and ensuring the program was only looking for relevant information yielded 100% matches.

I hope this helps, will happily run anyone through the process if necessary.

Have a lovely day!